# Can't connect to elasticache redis from docker container running in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, redis, docker-compose, amazon-elasticache

As a part of my CI process, I am creating a docker-machine EC2 instance and running 2 docker containers inside of it via docker-compose. The server container test script attempts to connect to an AWS elasticache redis instance within the same VPC as the EC2. When the test script is run I get the following error:

```
1) Storage
       check cache connection
         should return seeded value in redis:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/usr/src/app/test/scripts/test.js)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

**Update**: I can connect via redis-cli from the EC2 itself:

```
redis-cli -c -h ***.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 ping
> PONG
```

It looks like I cant connect to my redis instance because my docker container is using an IP that is not within the same VPC as my elasticache instance. How can I setup my docker config to use the same IP as the host machine while building my containers from remote images? Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant section of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/$REPOSITORY_NAME-server:github_ci_$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER
    container_name: $REPOSITORY_NAME-server
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "6379:6379"
    env_file: ./.env
```

Server container Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# create app dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080 6379

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Elasticache redis SG inbound rules:
[image]

EC2 SG inbound rules:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem through extensive trial and error. The major hint that pointed me in the right direction was found in the Docker docs:

[By default, the container is assigned an IP address for every Docker network it connects to. The IP address is assigned from the pool assigned to the network...](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname)

Elasticache instances are only accessible internally from their respective VPC. Based on my config, the docker container and the ec2 instance were running on 2 different IP addresses but only the EC2 IP was whitelisted to connect to Elasticache.

I had to bind the docker container IP to the host EC2 IP in my `docker.compose.yml` by setting the container `network_mode` to `"host"`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/$REPOSITORY_NAME-server:github_ci_$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER
    container_name: $REPOSITORY_NAME-server
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "6379:6379"
    network_mode: "host"
    env_file: ./.env
...
```